# Copy a row to another spreadsheet, edit and copy back again

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to negate the need for the users of a Workbook to use any other sheet except the 'Front' sheet. 
Sheet 2 holds all the data, and Sheet1 provides ways to search said data, but so far, not manipulate it.

I am trying to find a way for a row of data to be copied into Sheet1, edited, and then copied back to the right row in Sheet2. Is this possible?

So far, my 'Search' button brings data into Sheet1, but I can't work out a sensible way to edit and copy back to where it came from.. can anyone help?!
My original idea was to use the WorksheetChange function to mark a row that had been copied into Sheet1 and then edited (sometimes multiple rows will be copied but only one edited), and then I was going to work out a way to compare Serial numbers of those that had been marked with edited with those in Sheet 2 to try and copy it back to the right place... however, I thought that was quite convoluted and imagine there is a better way to do it. I also was unable to get the WorksheetChange function to work how I wanted it.. I just couldn't understand it properly, and perhaps it was the wrong function to use because it isn't specific enough.

Screenshots of the two sheets are here:

EDIT having trouble uploading the photos :

1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/ssy9s51ug2t1q99/sheet1.png?dl=0

[image]

2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4kyz1bw5kmupdro/sheet2.png?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't a userform be easier?

Comment: yes it probably would.. I didn't know such a thing was possible.. will look into that now. Thanks

Comment: Will userform allow me to pull information from a sheet into it to be edited and save it back again? Or does it only allow for new entries...?

Comment: A custom user form can be pretty much anything you want it to be: `inserts` `updates` or `deletes`. It's all up to your imagination / programming / design.